# How to mention a sender of a command? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a super simple `.report <person>` command. I have it so it will be sent to a certain channel when someone types it. What I wanted to do is have it display the name of the user who reported the other user. I don't know how to go about doing that. Does anyone know the best way?

```
@bot.command()
async def report(*, message):
    await bot.delete(message)
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("479177111030988810"), message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, where you take the context (ctx) and from it get the contents of the message and its author

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def report(ctx):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    report = f"\"{ctx.message.content[8:]}\"  sent by {ctx.message.author}"
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("479177111030988810"), report)
```

Comment: Does this actually @mention the user?
When I use {ctx.message.author} it only prints the username as a normal text string (example: BanjoFox#2731)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctx.author.mention` for mentioning the user. The `mention` attribute (documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Member.mention)) returns a string that you can use in the argument to `send`.

Example usage:

```py
@bot.command("hello", help="Learn about this bot")
async def hello(ctx: discord.commands.Context):
    await ctx.send(f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}! I'm a bot!")
```